# How to add a Key-Value in a Azure Key Vault?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I want to add a Key-Value for a SQL DB Connection string like:

Key: `DBConnectionString`

Value: `Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;`

In Azure Portal, I created a **Key Vault**. I brought up the page for the **Keys** link on the left side. On that page, I can add only a `Key` there and not a `Value`.

How can I add a `Key-Value`?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Key-Value pair in Azure Key Vault should be stored inside "Secrets" section. The Keys section is used to store encryption keys.